# How do I divide by the corresponding element in the list while using zip()

Tags: python

I am trying to find out how can I do `(i1+i2)/[i]` for the ith element before getting the mean.

```
import numpy as np

def avg_prod(l1, l2):
    np.mean([i1 * i2 for i1, i2 in zip(l1, l2)])
```

I tried to use `i` inside the code, but it produces an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
def avg_prod(l1, l2):
    np.mean([i1 * i2 / i for i, (i1, i2) in enumerate(zip(l1, l2))])
```

or iterate over indices:

```
def avg_prod(l1, l2):
    np.mean([l1[i] * l2[i] / i for i in range(min(len(l1), len(l2)))])
```

you can minimize it in case you are sure that the lengths of the lists are equal:

```
def avg_prod(l1, l2):
    np.mean([l1[i] * l2[i] / i for i in range(len(l1))])
```